# Kaggle notebook running cell requires input

Tags: python, bash, arguments, kaggle

I am running a kaggle notebook, and in one of my cells I have the command:

```
!python train.py
```

I got an a prompt for input:

```
wandb: (1) Create a W&B account
wandb: (2) Use an existing W&B account
wandb: (3) Don't visualize my results
wandb: Enter your choice:
```

However, I can't enter anything in that log cell. I can just see what is there. How can I proceed with my program? Can I perhaps force some number to be entered with the bash command? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can import wandb and then call `wandb.login()` before you call `!python train.py`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

In previous cell you should run:
!wandb off